# Problems after make init configuring a project

Tags: docker, make

I am configuring a project:

I execute make init,being init:

```
init:
    make _login
    mkdir -p node_modules
    mkdir -p docker/postgres
    make _docker-compose-up-ignore-errors
    sleep 5s
    make seed >> /dev/null
    make build
```

[make init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmHCn.png)

and this is what happened:

```
make seed >> /dev/null
make[1]: *** [Makefile:5: seed] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:28: init] Error 2
```

[final error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3rRI.png)

after this:

```
make seed >> /dev/null
```

[command I execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJyhb.png)

being `seed` as fallows:

```
    docker-compose exec api ./app seed
```

[seed command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6woO.png)

I am new to linux and to docker and docker-compose, I need help on this, my project is almost configured

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am not using ubuntu but linux mint 20

Comment: Sorry Mint is not Ubuntu and not supported on this Ubuntu only site.

Comment: changing to ubuntu then